# How do I display a value of a derived cell address using the CELL command?

Tags: excel

I am using the following to discover the address of the cell with the smallest value from within a range of cells:

=CELL("address",OFFSET(E1,MATCH(MIN(E1:E400),E1:E400,0)-1,0))

But it displays the actual address rather than the value of the address (e.g. $A$12).  How would I get it to display the actual value of the cell that it finds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the smallest value in a range of cells, then you can use this simple formula (from your question) on its own:-

```
=MIN(E1:E400)
```

Comment: Thanks, Fred.  When I searched Google for how to find the cell with the smallest value, the formula that I listed is what came up.  I actually had to search for LARGE and then find what the opposite of that was.  Most times Google is great, but sometimes it can miss the most obvious things. :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on the most convoluted method, you could add the [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) function as a 'wrapper'.

```
=INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET(E1,MATCH(MIN(E1:E400),E1:E400,0)-1,0)))
```

TBH, seems like a waste of calculation cycles to me.

[image: min_E.]

With your formula in H2, I 'wrapped' it with INDIRECT in G2. Given that you have expressed that you needed to also get the cell address, this may have been written as,

```
=INDIRECT(H2)
```

Note that you are working with volatile¹ functions.

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: Yes, it is.  I didn't realize I could just use MIN.  But I still need the address, so it's not a complete waste of research!  :-)

Comment: BTW, I tried adding INDIRECT and it didn't work.  It kept wanting to just convert the whole string into just plain text.  Or throw an error that it couldn't figure out what formula I was trying to perform.